# Incrementing within nested loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, increment, nested-loops

I have a pretty straight forward question. In the program below, why does i not increment to 1 in the first iteration of the for loop? My compiler shows that for the first run, j is not less than i because they are both 0. Thanks!

```
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < i) {
      System.out.print(j + " ");
      j++;
```

Comment: Why would `i` be incremented during the first iteration? The only time you have `i` being incremented is at the end of the first iteration.

Comment: In First iteration of loop, `i=0` as specified in inital condition of for loop.

Comment: If you want to start at 1, initialize i as 1, otherwise it will only increment after the first loop is finished!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `i` will be 0 for the first iteration and 1 for the second. Take the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // loop code
}
```

The above for loop is just syntactic sugar for:

```
{ 
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
        // loop code
        i++;
    }
}
```

Note that the outer braces are there to show that after the for loop exits the variable `i` is no longer in scope.

Comment: @flakes Good point. Adding braces around whole expression to show scoping.

Answer (score -1):

```
while (j <= i)
```

Output: 0 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 4